# How to turn a copper/zinc penny battery rechargeable?

Tags: electrochemistry, electricity

I just saw the [copper+zinc+vinegar](https://youtu.be/vIHfUJu3aKo) battery also known as "[penny battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_battery)" and I thought it would be perfect to make at home since I don't know anything about chemistry.

In the wikipedia page linked it is said that the process is **irreversible**, so the battery can't be recharged.

Searching a bit I've seen [here](http://www.cumulusenergystorage.com/technology) that some company [patented their Copper/Zinc rechargeable batteries](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20160013485A1/en) (patent link).

However, I couldn't make heads of its structure, I'm not trying to make a industrial level battery, just a homemade simple thing.

In order to make it rechargeable, I just need to put the zinc and copper inside their own separator (like in lead batteries in cars or ion-lithium batteries, I believe) and fill it with vinegar, right? Or there is something else to it?

Comment: This is just a variant of the lemon “battery”. It is not rechargeable. Also, look up the Daniell cell.

Comment: You can benefit greatly by getting this and working through it: K. Schmidt-Rohr, "How Batteries Store and Release Energy: Explaining Basic Electrochemistry", J. Chem. Ed., 95 (10) (2018) 1801-1810. The Zn and Cu Daniell cell is addressed in great detail. TL; DR Cohesive energy differences are the major factor in explaining the behavior of this famous galvanic cell.

Comment: Now cross posted at EE SE: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/633077/223146.

Comment: On the other side of the coin, you could use two lead "slugs" to make a rechargeable cell.